# Can I treat an NSManagedObject the same way as a regular NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsobject

I am new to `core data` and I'm trying to get my head round how to make use of `NSManagedObjects`. Basically I have several objects that I intend to store using `core data` (which have relationships with each other).

Before looking into core data I wrote a basic model that consisted of 3 `NSObjects`, now I have created a `core data model` and generated 3 `NSManagedObjects` from this model. I have some logic in my existing 3 `NSObjects` (eg. designated initializers and specialised getters and setters) which I still want to make use of.

My question is whether I can just transfer the logic from the 3 `NSObjects` directly to the 3 `NSManagedObjects` then use them as I would in my original design (with the added bonus of being able to easily persist them), or whether I need to keep both the `NSObjects` as well as the `NSManagedObject`.

Please could someone advise on the best design practices, I would like to keep my code as clean and well structured as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `NSManagedObject` inherits from `NSObject`, you don't loose functionality if you simply change the superclass of your custom classes from `NSObject` to `NSManagedObject` - provided that you don't have method/property names that collide with that of `NSManagedObject`. This way you don't have to keep the orignal classes, making the code cleaner and the logic simpler.

Answer (score 6):

When i have to add extra functionality for NSManagedObject i create category and keep it in separated file, because when I modify .xcdatamodeld file I usually override NSManagedObject subclasses instead of make changes in updated files manually.

Offer+Localized.h:

```
#import "Offer.h"
@interface Offer (Localized)
- (NSString *) localizedPrice;
@end
```

Offer+Localized.m:

```
@implementation Offer (Localized)

- (NSString *) localizedPrice;
{
    if ( self.price > 0 ) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Price: %d", nil), self.price];
    } else {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"Free", nil);
    }
}

@end
```